# Connect to a remote system

Tags: ssh, port, remote-access, 3g

We want to access to a remote system that is connected to the Internet by an Ethernet connection with a 3G-router. For this, we have a script running on the machine that will open some ports on a server, by connecting to the correct opened port we can access the machine interface. It is a routine that is already running on the same kind of system and all works great.

This time, the connection is correctly established, we can connect to the machine's interface but after a very short time we lose it. This happens every times.

The only thing that could have change with the previous installation is the router configuration. This configuration is almost vanilla, the only change from default is the 3G interface (and the wifi for installation purpose) that have been configured.

So my question is : **What could possibly go wrong and interfere with this setup ? and Is there something in a router configuration able to trouble the correct behaviour ?**

Comment: Is the connection going idle? Idle connections may be timed out.

Comment: The running script send some data every minutes to kept the connection active. The connection once broke up when we were in the terminal command of the remote machine with ssh.